# html-jquery,selected option make visible next option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where is connected two select option.

Now is this:

```html
<form>
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option>Please select the first option</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

After the submit its coming this:

```html
<form>
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option selected>4</option>
    </select>
    <select>
       <option>41</option>
       <option>42</option>
       <option>43</option>
       <option>44</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

How can I make without form submit to call the next selection data?

Comment: thats why we use javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript XMLHttpRequest. If your server gives the response as select options use this code directly. Else parse the response and put it inside your select tag. The JS fiddle is 
https://jsfiddle.net/w123ywdo/

```
<form>
    <select onchange="changeFirstSelect(this)">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
    <select id="second">
        <option>Please select the first option</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The JS code is

```
var changeFirstSelect = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: I use POST method. What I need to change? GET -> POST?

Comment: You can still use POST with an xhr request.

Comment: `xhr.open('POST', 'http://example.com', true); xhr.send(param);` where param is the param you want to send